# React Native infinite loop

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I declared and initialized the variable like this:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
```

Then make a function like this:

```
const getUser2 = async () => {
    try {
      const user2 = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
      let parsed = JSON.parse(user2)
      setUser(parsed)
      console.warn('1')
    } catch(err) {}
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUser2()
    return () => getUser2()
})
```

The **problem** is when I run it, it produces an infinite loop like this:
[image]

**Why does it loop infinitely?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add dependency array, Then it will get called only once -

```
useEffect(() => {
    getUser2()
    return () => getUser2()
}, [])
```

Go through this reference for better understanding of useEffect - https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-to-react-useeffect-hook/

In your `useEffect` you haven't added any dependency array, so on each re-render this `useEffect`  is getting called, when you add `[ ]` dependency as a parameter to `useEffect` then it will act as `componentDidMount` which get called only once.

Comment: It works! I don't know what's happening but it works lol. Thank you @Kailash

Comment: Thanks for the additional answer <3

Answer (score 1):

useEffect will be triggered every time the setState is set, if you do not pass the second parameter